# Can SSDP still be enable after turning off uPnP?

Tags: upnp

I am watching my LAN traffic a bit to see if or what a new Chinese phone on the LAN does.
I turned off uPnP on the internet router but see SSDP in some traffic. Curiously, that is (as far as I understand) a version of uPnP but my router has no option to disable it.

Comment: Whether or not devices on the network are going to speak a certain protocol has little to do with how your router is configured. In fact, SSDP is designed to operate without relying on a server.

Comment: Yes, the devices emit the SSDP messages, the router receives them and logs them, but I think or hope that the (WiFi) router stops those messages from reaching other devices on the LAN. The router stops uPnP from the WAN. My question is what can I do about SSDP on the LAN I guess.

Comment: Within a LAN, the router doesn't do any sort of filtering since it is typically acting like a switch at L2, unless you have a non-typical setup.

Comment: So it won't transfer any packets across the LAN? Do you have an idea of how to test this ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Use Wireshark on another device in the network to see the traffic the device is sending.

Answer (score 1):

> that is (as far as I understand) a version of uPnP but my router has no option to disable it.

Not exactly, no. UPnP is a *collection* of protocols; SSDP is its discovery protocol, i.e. the mechanism by which UPnP-capable devices can find other devices.

When you talk about "UPnP" in routers, that usually refers to two specific protocols: SSDP to find the router and UPnP IGD/IGD2 to control it. Similarly, "UPnP" in a media player would mean SSDP for discovery and UPnP AV for streaming/control.

When you disable the entire UPnP feature on the router, you disable both protocols at once.

> I turned off uPnP on the internet router

When you disable "UPnP" on a router, you only stop the router *itself* from ever responding to UPnP IGD requests or from being found via SSDP searches.

But although the router can refuse to receive packets, it cannot stop other hosts from sending them. Whenever some of your hosts send packets start SSDP device discovery, the router can do absolutely nothing to prevent those packets from being sent – all it can do is stay quiet and not respond.

(For that matter the hosts might not even be searching for routers – they might be searching for printers or media centres, which can also use UPnP.)